# Example on pseudo-groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

**Definition:**
‎A *pseudo-group* is a collection $\mathcal{G}$ of (locally defined) invertible smooth diffeomorphisms of a manifold $M$. ‎The simplest example of a pseudo-group is the collection of all local diffeomorphism of a manifold $M$.

**Example:**
Consider the infinite-dimensional Lie pseudo-group‎

$$‎X=x,\qquad Y=y\,f(x)+\phi (x),\qquad Z=z(f(x))^x+\psi(x)‎,$$

‎where $f,\phi,\psi\in C^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ and $f(x)>0$‎.

Obviously, $X,Y$ and $Z$ are the target coordinates. Indeed, the pseudo-group acts on the coordinate $(x,y,z)$ and transforms it to the target coordinate $(X,Y,Z)$.

**My questions:**

1. what are the group parameters??
2. If we split the cotangent bundle into horizontal and vertical forms, what are the vertical forms?

**Reference**

*Olver, Peter J.; Pohjanpelto, Juha; Valiquette, Francis*, [**On the structure of Lie pseudo-groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.3842/SIGMA.2009.077), SIGMA, Symmetry Integrability Geom. Methods Appl. 5, Paper 077, 14 p. (2009). [ZBL1241.58008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1241.58008).